# User creation in grails web app with spring security & CAS?

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas

There is an ample documentation about how to configure a grails web app to use Spring Security + CAS for Single Sign On but there not much about how the users will be created. If grails client apps G1 & G2 are connecting to the CAS app C1 but have different users attributes, permissions & relationships with other domain objects, then how should store the users in the DBs for G1 & G2 yet authenticate it against CAS server? For instance in G1, one user could have multiple accounts and in G2 one user has only one account OR for instance in G1, one user has roles 'ADMIN' & 'SUPERADMIN' and in G2 user has roles 'MANAGER' & 'SUPERVISOR'.